# Can CiviRules add a contact to an event?

Tags: civievent, recurring-contributions, civirules

I've had a situation where we needed to offer a recurring payment possibility for an event. Hmmm... This is not at all native to CiviEvent as far as I can see. (I looked into using Webforms, as well as Repeating Events.)

The plan was to make a contribution page to create the recurring contribution subsription. So far so good! And then make a CiviRule to detect when a payment has been made as above. That's fine too.

And then use CiviRules to add the person to a specific event, preferably along with a statement in the Participant Fee Level fee.

However, it looks like CiviRules is not yet set up to registering people to Events. Is that true?

Thanks for your help.

Civi 5.24, Drupal 7.69.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at present - I've investigated this myself in the past.  You can find a [complete list of actions](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/blob/master/sql/actions.json) in their repository (though of course other extensions add actions).

I considered writing the action but it turned out to be complex.  A rule that adds everyone to a pre-determined event is easy enough - but creating a UI that could handle actions like "Add contact to the next workshop" proved trickier and not worth the effort (for me, YMMV).

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful!